# R Package segmented with an offset term

Tags: r, offset, glm, data-fitting

I am using package [segmented](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf) in R. I first fitted a Poisson glm with a log link function using the `glm` function that includes an offset term like:

```
M1=glm(Y~X1+X2+X3+offset(log(X)),data=dat.1,family=poisson)
```

M1 is fitted without any error. Next I tried to fit a segmented `glm` by using the package segmented in R as:

```
library(segmented)
seg.1=segmented(M1,seg.Z=~X1,psi=list(X1=c(0.5)))
```

I am having the following error:

```
Error in offset(log(X)) : object 'X' not found
```

Where is my mistake here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly providing the location of `X` (e.g. `sample_dat$X`) in the call to `glm` does the trick.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(segmented)

# sample data
set.seed(101)
sample_dat <- data.frame(Y = rpois(100, 3), X1 = rnorm(100), X2 = rnorm(100), X = rpois(100, 100))

# fit model 
M1 = glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = sample_dat, offset = log(sample_dat$X), family = poisson)
seg.1 = segmented(M1, seg.Z=~X1, psi=list(X1 = c(0.5)), data = sample_dat)
```