# Using R package segmentet on poisson regression with offset

Tags: r, regression, glm, piecewise

I am trying to use the segmented function on a poisson regression with offset in R (version 3.1.1). My segmented packages i version 0.4-0.0.

In an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034403/r-package-segmented-with-an-offset-term/19038941#19038941?newreg=da2aced311fb4df297c21156a9f16823) a reproducible example was given:

```
# sample data
set.seed(101)
sample_dat <- data.frame(Y = rpois(100, 3), X1 = rnorm(100), X2 = rnorm(100), X = rpois(100, 100))

# fit model 
M1 = glm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = sample_dat, offset = log(sample_dat$X), family = poisson)
seg.1 = segmented(M1, seg.Z=~X1, psi=list(X1 = c(0.5)), data = sample_dat)
```

however I cannot reproduce the example - I get an error saying:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ Y + sample_dat + Y ~ X1 + X2 +  : object is not a matrix
```

does anyone else have the same problem? Or even better - an explanation?

Thank you

/Kira

Comment: Setting the random seed is part of a reproducible example.

Comment: After testing this, it seems `segmented.glm` doesn't deal correctly with the `offset` and botches the formula if one is specified.

Comment: Btw, the package maintainer was quite responsive when I reported a problem in the past. You should consider sending him an e-mail.

Comment: Thank you - I'll write him. The original example did feature a seed - I just didn't manage to copy it due to clumsyness - its fixed :-).

Comment: As a workaround, see if including the offset in the formula fixes the problem: `Y ~ X1 + X2 + offset(log(X))` and no separate `offset=` argument.

Comment: @Hong Ooi  
I tried that to - and I did get a different error - still concerning the model.frame.deafault though  
    _Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + sample_dat + X +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'sample_dat'_

Comment: Don't include the `sample_dat$` bit in the offset, whether as part of the formula or a separate argument. The code knows to look in the supplied data frame for the offset.

Comment: @HongOoi I know its been a long time but it would be great if you added this as an answer so op can accept it - I've had the same problem and I almost blew past this question because it had no answer